# Print variable value dynamically based on selected language

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem displaying data, where i have to print variable value based on selected language. Let me explain my issue further with examples.

I have two options for displaying some text

```
<template>
   {{i.translations.en.header}}
   {{i.translations.sl.header}}
</template>
```

And i have function which read selected locale from coockie

```
export default {
    name: 'myComponent',
    data() {
        return { 
            selectedLanguage: '',
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getFrontPageSlides();
        this.selectedLanguage = Cookie.get('locale');
        console.log(this.selectedLanguage);
        // returns en or sl if i print
    },
}
```

My question is how to properly format my variables so template syntax will show desired value?

I have already tried `{{i.translations.selectedLanguage.header}}` and `{{i.translations.this.selectedLanguage.header}}`, but i only get errors

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and I will provide. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do:

```
{{i.translations[selectedLanguage].header}}
```

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: omg! Of course! :D brain stops working after whole day of coding! :D

Comment: @Valor_ Hehe, I know the feeling!

Comment: @Valor_ No problem :)